# modelsummary output to LaTeX with automatic column width and line breaks

Tags: latex, kable, modelsummary

I estimate a model with `estimatr::lm_robust` and display the model output with `modelsummary::modelsummary`. Consider the following example:

```
df <- tibble(x=runif(100, 0, 100)) %>% mutate(y=x*(2+runif(100, 0, 10)), z=rep(c(1:10), 10))

tab <- modelsummary::modelsummary(
  list("A very, very long title that will span multiple lines"=estimatr::lm_robust(data=df, clusters=z, y~x),
       "A short title"=estimatr::lm_robust(data=df, y~x),
       "A very, very long title that will span multiple lines"=estimatr::lm_robust(data=df, clusters=z, y~x),
       "A short title"=estimatr::lm_robust(data=df, y~x)),
  title = "This table should be on one landscape page in LaTeX with automatically adjusted column width and line breaks",
  notes = c("A note that is very long and says many things and will span multiple lines where I would like automatic line breaks in LaTeX"),
  output="kableExtra")
```

I now want to perform some `kableExtra` manipulations:

```
tab %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "M1" = 1, "M2" = 1, "M3" = 2)) %>%
  row_spec(3, color = 'red') %>%
  row_spec(5, background = 'lightblue') %>% 
  column_spec(1, width="10.5cm")
```

I want to ensure that the table overall has the full page width (be it landscape or portrait) and line breaks automatically included. **How do I best do this?**

Further, I want save to `.tex`. However, `tab %>% ... %>% save_kable(format = "latex", file = "latex_table.tex")` gives an empty file. **What am I doing wrong?**

Can someone point me into the right direction?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to add `kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down")` for full page width! And maybe check [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf) out for line breaks.

Comment: Thank you @Julian! I am still struggling to export it to LaTeX though - am I making an obvious mistake?

Comment: I would try it without the pipe, ie `save_kable(x = tab, format...`